# Problemas al importar MatTableModule en Angular 11.2.3 de la libreria de Material.angular.io

Tags: angular, material-design

### Al tratar de importar import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'; me marca el siguiente error:
Cliente Angular: 11.2.3
@angular/material:  ^11.2.4
@angular/cdk: ^11.2.4

```
Error: ./nodemodules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/table.js 22:12
```

Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (22:12)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/cdk/table';
  |

> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
> | const _c0 = [[["caption"]], [["colgroup"], ["col"]]];
> | const _c1 = ["caption", "colgroup, col"];

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/table.js 9:12
Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (9:12)

- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
- ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | import * as ɵngcc3 from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
  |

> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
> | import * as ɵngcc1 from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
> | import * as ɵngcc2 from '@angular/cdk/platform';

---

Sin embargo tengo importadas estas librerias y no me dan problema:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me sucedía el mismo problema. Lo que hice para solucinarlo fue:

- Eliminar la carpeta `node_modules`
- Reinstalar usando el comando `npm instal`

Comment: Si gracias, lo solucioné muy parecido reinstalando esas librerías: npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk